# Confidence interval for effect size includes zero but significant?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, statsmodels

Hi everyone (first time user here),

I am working on a paper and I am quite familiar with regression methods, but I am stuck... we have generated an effect size.

[image]

Our beta is the largest in the model (-5.48), significant (p = .021), but weirdly crosses zero which I have never seen before in the CI (-10.17, 0.12). Anyone ever encounter this before? I have been searching with co-authors to try to figure out why and we have not idenfitied any coding issues, so we are treating this as a valid calculation that we are not sure how to interpret given it's significant but the CI crosses zero.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or resources.

Comment: Please provide more details about the analysis and results, as this one line from a model summary doesn't provide much information. I do note, however, that the CI do not seem to be symmetric about the point estimate of -5.48. Any reason why that might be the case?

Comment: We don't even have column headings on that table. (The table would generally be better presented with text rather than a picture; for one thing, vision-impaired users who read the site with the help of a screen-reader will know what it says. It's possible to format a text-table in several ways)